# Horizontal table for many variables with the same categories

Tags: r

I'm looking for an easy way to make a table in R that shows each variable as a row in the dataframe and then each variable category as the column of the dataframe. In each cell the frequency of that category should be displayed and then the sum is the last column. The point is to display distribution for different variables with the same categories easily. I have included to a picture to show what I'm looking for.

[image]

I have managed to produce some code that achieves what I want, but it takes a lot of time to do this for each variable i want to include in the table.

```
mydata <- as.data.frame((table(mydat$var)))
mydata <- as.data.frame(t(mydata))
mydata <- lapply(mydata, as.numeric)
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)
mydata$sum <- (mydata$category 1 + mydata$category 2 + mydata$category 3)
mydata[-c(1), ]
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

To add more variables I imagine that i could use rbind(), but there might be some easier way to achieve something similar?

Here is a reproducible example using the mtcars dataset.

```
    data("mtcars")
tdata <- as.data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl))
tdata1 <- as.data.frame(t(tdata))
tdata2 <- lapply(tdata1, as.numeric)
tdata3 <- as.data.frame(tdata2)
tdata3$sum <- (tdata3$V1 + tdata3$V2 + tdata3$V3)

tdata3 <- tdata3[-c(1),]

tdata3
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Your code as illustrated will not work. You overwrite `mydata` repeatedly so `mydata$catetory 1` is destroyed by the first line of code. That would not work anyway since spaces are not allowed in variable names. without quotations, e.g. `mydata$"category 1"`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Yes, I have added a reproducible example in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `data.frame` where each variable has the same categories (as in your example):

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = c(rep("Cat1", 30),
                      rep("Cat2", 10),
                      rep("Cat3", 20) ),
            Var2 = c(rep("Cat1", 10),
                      rep("Cat2", 20),
                      rep("Cat3", 30) ),
            Var3 = c(rep("Cat1", 5),
                      rep("Cat2", 25),
                      rep("Cat3", 30) ) )
```

You could use `lapply()` to apply the `table()` function to every column in your data.frame:

```
tab <- lapply(colnames(df), function(x) table(df[, x]))
```

As `lapply()` outputs a list, use `do.call` to bind them, and `rowSums()` to create the sum column:

```
tab <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, t(tab)))
tab$Sum <- rowSums(tab)
# add variable labels as rows
rownames(tab) <- colnames(df)
```

The output will look like this:

```
     Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 Sum
Var1   30   10   20  60
Var2   10   20   30  60
Var3    5   25   30  60
```

And, you could throw all this in a function:

```
my_tab_fun <- function(df) {
    tab <- lapply(colnames(df), 
           function(x) table(df[, x]))
    tab <- data.frame(
            do.call(rbind, t(tab)))
    tab$Sum <- rowSums(tab)
    rownames(tab) <- colnames(df)
    return(tab)
    }

my_tab_fun(df)
```